# Is this a sign of a successful XSS attack?

Tags: web-application, xss

I'm just testing a basic XSS injection attack. Given the images below, does it look like this website is vulnerable to XSS?

Is whitelisting the characters still the best practice against XSS attacks?

[image: Form with XSS payload.] [image: Form with HTML-encoded payload.]

Answer (score 2):

From your screen shots, this page does not seem to be vulnerable to XSS.

The correct way to prevent XSS is by using *output encoding*. If a user types `<script>` and the page puts `<script>` in the HTML source, it is vulnerable to XSS. If it instead encodes that user input and puts `&lt;script&gt;` in the HTML source, it is not interpreted as HTML but as the text `<script>`.

It looks like your site does this encoding twice instead of once, and this results in displaying the encoded HTML in the text fields.

Answer (score 0):

The example within the question seems to show that they're preventing the tags from being used by targeting them. E.g. `<script>` becoming `&lt;script&gt;`. However, if UTF encodes it and then SQL encodes it into something else,  it's not technically secure. Therefore, using a different type of injection method can be used, which is an *SQL injection* and can be exploited by hex values, as shown below:

**First you choose something to be encoded:**

[image: Hex Encoder]

**This will then be encoded to form this:**

[image: Hex Decoder]

**Then you can carry out the attack:**

Here is an example of this from OWASP, when testing for a possible injection:

```
Select user from users where name = unhex('726F6F74')
```

Here 'root' is shown as the hex value 726F6F74

**Sources:**

HTML.Encode() : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014593/html-encode-what-how-does-it-prevent-scripting-security-problems-in-asp-net

SQL Injection: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

OWASP example1: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_(OTG-INPVAL-005)#Hex_Encoding

OWASP evasion: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Another example can be found here: https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-cheat-sheet/#HexbasedSamples

Comment: Most of your answer is explaing a quite specific case of SQL-injeciton, which isn't what the question is about. I think you should focus on the XSS that the question is about, without getting into details about anything else.